# I'm getting no console output using SLF4J-Log4J in Gradle

Tags: gradle, logging, binding, log4j, slf4j

I want to configure slf4j-log4j in my custom gradle plugin and simply cant get it to work. Log outputs are not printed to the console

My configuration looks like this:

I created a **"log4j2.xml"** in my gradle plugin project under **/src/main/resources**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="INFO">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n" />
        </Console>
        <File name="Audit" fileName="./logs/audit.log" immediateFlush="false" append="false">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
        </File>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="debug">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console" />
            <AppenderRef ref="Audit"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

**build.gradle**

```gradle
dependencies {
    implementation group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-api', version: '2.17.2'
    implementation group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-core', version: '2.17.2'
    implementation group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-slf4j-impl', version: '2.17.2'
}
```

**I'm now calling a task from the plugin**

```groovy
project.tasks.register('log-test') {
  Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.class)

  logger.info('##### INFO #####')
  logger.error('##### ERROR #####')
  logger.debug('##### DEBUG #####')
}
```

I'm only getting the error & gradle standard output :

```bash
> Task :logtest:log-test UP-TO-DATE

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 144ms
8 actionable tasks: 8 up-to-date
##### ERROR #####
22:50:11: Execution finished 'log-test'.
```

I put a breakpoint on the StaticLoggerBinder class to inspect which implementation is used. It seems that the gradle default is used, instead of the log4j one:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Unfortunately, I found the answer:** [https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/2408](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/userguide_single.html?_ga=2.939764.479847046.1677169091-1341969977.1675872353#sec:changing_what_gradle_logs)

see also : [Gradle User Forums - Logging in Gradle Plugin](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/logging-in-gradle-plugin/31685/6)

The only option for now is to replace the whole logging:
[Gradle 8.0.2 Custom Logging](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/userguide_single.html?_ga=2.939764.479847046.1677169091-1341969977.1675872353#sec:changing_what_gradle_logs)

I've written a small workaround, so that it is possible to print out debug log messages from my own classes, without having all the gradle internal debug messages in the console too

```groovy
import org.gradle.api.logging.LogLevel
import org.gradle.api.logging.Logger
import org.gradle.api.logging.Logging

class LoggerFascade {
    private Logger log

    private static LogLevel level

    LoggerFascade(Class clazz) {
        this.log = Logging.getLogger(clazz)

    }

    static LoggerFascade getLogger(Class clazz) {
        return new LoggerFascade(clazz)
    }

    static void setLevel(LogLevel newLevel) {
        if (newLevel != level) {
            level = newLevel
        }
    }

    static LogLevel getLevel() {
        return level
    }

    void lifecyle(String message) {
        log.lifecycle(message)
    }

    // eg. trace
    void quiet(String message) {
        if(LoggerFascade.level == LogLevel.QUIET) {
            log.lifecycle(message)
        }
    }

    void debug(String message) {
        if(LoggerFascade.level == LogLevel.DEBUG) {
            log.lifecycle(message)
        }
    }

    void error(String message) {
        log.error(message)
    }
}
```

and can now set the log level to “debug” and have all log messages from my custom plugin classes logged to the console:

```groovy
class CustomPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {
    private static final LoggerFascade log = LoggerFascade.getLogger(CustomPlugin.class)

    @Override
    void apply(Project project) {
      LoggerFascade.setLevel(LogLevel.DEBUG)
      log.debug("watch out, I'm a debug message :)")
    }
}
```